# Node ncp copy without overwriting (no clobber) in command line mode

Tags: node.js

GNU copy has the `-n` flag to copy without overwriting like so:

`cp -n config.ini.dist config.ini`

Is there a way to get the same functionality from [the npm package ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) on the command line?

My aim is to copy a distributed configuration file for a npm package:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepare": "ncp config.dist.ini config.ini -n",
  ...
```

However it does not know the `-n` flag and overwrites existing files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll down the page of the documentation link you provided, you’ll find that setting the clobber option to false will do what you’re asking for.

> options.clobber - boolean=true. if set to false, ncp will not overwrite destination files that already exist.

For command line use, it appears from looking at their source code that the CLI does not expose the 'clobber' option to the CLI.  Fortunately, it's pretty easy to fix this yourself with your own little utility:

```
//./bin/ncp
#!/usr/env node
const ncp = require('ncp').ncp;

ncp.limit = 16;

// note: also add error handling.  I'm also being explicit here, you can 
//       use their bin file for a more extensive example: https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp/blob/master/bin/ncp
const source = process.argv[2];
const destination = process.argv[3];

// note you can get fancier and read the options in from the CLI if you want, I'm just assuming you know what you want to always use here. 
ncp(source, destination, { clobber: false }, function (err) {
 if (err) {
   return console.error(err);
   process.exit(1);
 }
 console.log('done!');
 process.exit(1):
});
```

Then in  your package.json you can just do

```
"scripts": { "prepare": "./bin/ncp config.ini.dist config.ini"}}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I want to use it on the command line to put it in package.json. I edited the question.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. The question is unedited and how would you copy a file into package.json?

Comment: I added "on the command line". What I mean is this:   `"scripts": {  "prepare": "cp config.ini.dist config.ini"}}`. But I don't want to overwrite the configuration file if it already exists and is potentially modifed. As far as I know I can't use ncp programatically from within `package.json`.

Comment: @KonradHöffner Ok, that'd be good to include the in the question (the explicit example).  It really wasn't clear from the original question that that's what you're looking for.  I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I edited it again and hope it is better now. Thanks for the swift response and the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cp in windows like this

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build && npm run build:server && npm run cp",
    "build:server": "tsc --build server/tsconfig.json",
    "cp": "@powershell cp server/config.json,server/notice.json dist/server",
...
```

'@powershell' will run cp as powershell command